# How to explain the result of the two functins?

Tags: plotting

***How to explain the result of the two functins?***

Input1:

```
myperiodic[func_, {val_Symbol, min_?NumberQ, max_?NumberQ}] := 
func /. (val :> Mod[val - min, max - min] + min);
Plot[myperiodic[t, {t, -5, 5}] // Evaluate, {t, -40, 40}]
```

Input2:

```
f[t_] := If[-5 <= t <= 5, t, If[t > 0, f[t - 10], f[t + 10]]];
Plot[f[t] // Evaluate, {t, -40, 40}]
```

[image: How to explain?]

Comment: I have no idea what kind of answer you want here. Can you clarify what exactly you want explained

Comment: @ ssch,Why it is different of two graphics?

Comment: Try the Plot option [`Exclusions -> None`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exclusions.html) in input one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why this has been received poorly.  The answer is far from obvious.  Perhaps it is a duplicate but if so the duplicate should have been proposed.

Anyway, the answer lies in the way that `Plot` handles discontinuities in functions.  When it is able to identify them mathematically as discontinuities it does not plot them (it picks up the pen, if you will) if [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exclusions.html) is set to `True` (or `Automatic` resolves to `True`).

You must realize that `If` is a *programming* construct, not a mathematical one, and therefore it is opaque to this kind of analysis as far as *Mathematica* is concerned.

Observe these results:

```
f0[x_] /; x > 5 := 0
f0[x_] := x
f1 = If[# > 5, 0, #] &;
f2 = Piecewise[{{#, # < 5}}, 0] &;
f3 = Mod[#, 5] &;
f4 = UnitStep[5 - #] # &;

Plot[#[x], {x, 0, 10}] & /@ {f0, f1, f2, f3, f4}
```

[image]

Note that the discontinuities of the first two functions are not recognized, but the last three are.

Also, it is important to understand that `Plot` uses symbolic evaluation in its analysis.  If you prevent a function from evaluating symbolically `Plot` will not be able to map it:

```
f5[a_?NumericQ] := UnitStep[5 - a] a

Plot[f5[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Another examples: discontinues in `HeavisideTheta`,`Sign`, `FractionalPart`, `IntegerPart`, `Floor`, `Ceilings`, `Round`, `SquareWave`, `SawtoothWave` are recognized but not in `UnitBox` and `HeavisidePi`.